# Copy oracle table data from two tables to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

Here are my tables:

> create table country(
> country_id number(5) primary key,
> country varchar2(36)
> );
>
> ```
>     create table city(
>     city_id number(5) primary key,
>     country_id number(5) constraint city_country_fk references country(country_id) NOT NULL,
>     city varchar2(36)
>     );
>
> SQL> desc airportdemodata;
>  Name                    Null?    Type
>  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
>  AIRPORT_ID                  NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
>  IATA_CODE                        VARCHAR2(3)
>  CITY                         VARCHAR2(36)
>  COUNTRY                      VARCHAR2(36)
>  AIRPORT                      VARCHAR2(58)
> ```

I inserted countries from airportdemodata to country table as under:

```
INSERT INTO country (country)
SELECT unique(country) from airportdemodata;
```

it worked fine. 
Now I am trying to copy airportdemodata.city into city.city(country_id,city) by matching airportdemodata.country with country.country. I tried like this:

```
SQL> SELECT a.unique(city), b.country_id FROM airportdemodata a, country b where a.country=b.country;
SELECT a.unique(city), b.country_id FROM airportdemodata a, country b where a.country=b.country
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right; inventing your own syntax usually leads to the outcome you experienced. Did you mean to use `distinct`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.city,
                b.country_id
FROM airportdemodata a
JOIN country b ON a.country = b.country;
```

Comment: what is difference between unique and distinct?

Comment: Actually, none. I've been using DISTINCT probably 100% times and UNIQUE 0%. It is the way you used it; not `SELECT a.unique(city) ...` but `SELECT unique a.city ...`